# jQuery scrollLeft to certain position/page coordinates

Tags: jquery, coordinates

Quick question for a jQuery newbie... looked thru a bunch of google searches and the questions here and I cant seem to find an answer.

I am using this code to scroll left on my site. I have a fixed nav on the left and I would like the divs I am scrolling to come to the right of the nav instead of flush left. got everything working except where the scrolling stops.

here's the jquery script I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);

                // if you want to use one of the easing effects:
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                }, 2000,'easeInOutExpo');

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                }, 2000);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

any help or direction would be greatly, greatly appreciated!
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any HTML/Fiddle, i would have to guess that your line :

```
scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
```

should be :

```
scrollLeft: $('a[href='+$anchor.attr('href')+']').offset().left
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! ok, another quick question... right now the script works so i know it's right but i want it to scroll to left 52px instead of 0. where would i put that number?

Comment: `$('a[href='+$anchor.attr('href')+']').offset().left + 52 `

Comment: hmmm... seems now each of the nav buttons just scrolls left 52 px. i stink at this. thoughts? thanks in advance

Comment: OK you want that only home goes to 52. You'll need a conditional. The simplest way, but not the best, is to write that befor animation: `var position = $('a[href='+$anchor.attr('href')+']').offset().left == 0 ? 52 : $('a[href='+$anchor.attr('href')+']').offset().left` and then in animation do : `scrollLeft: position`

Comment: i would like all the buttons home included to scroll left at 0,52 so all the the content scrolls to right of the fixed nav bar

Comment: here's the page: http://universalpartnership.org/index_redo5.html. see how when the nav buttons are pressed the section goes behind the nav instead of just to the right of it?

Comment: Now that i see your HTML code, i don't how the code i provided work for you since it's really not how i imagined it ahah. Just do `offset().left - (your menu width)`.

Comment: like this? universalpartnership.org/index_redo5.html i seem to have lost the animation and it's still not going to right. why do i suck at this so bad? :/ thank you for being patient with me and for all your help!

Comment: Sweet! I got it to work doing what you directed! Forgot I was messing around with the code I posted! THANK YOU SO, SO MUCH!